# EF6 postgresql database first, can't generate model

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ado.net

I'm following [a tutorial](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/tutorial_ef.html) to generate model for existing postgresql database.
I created a console application and added these NuGet packages:
`EntityFramework (6.2.0), Npgsql(2.2.7), Npgsql.EntityFramework(2.2.7).`

The problem is that I [can't find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDfoD.png) PostgreSQL Database in the Data Source list while creating ADO.NET Entity Data model.

Does anyone know solution of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need the Visual Studio extension for PostgreSQL. Then the option for connecting to the database should show up.

Right now you installed all the NuGet packages for your code to work but Visual Studio still needs the extension to be able to create entities from existing PostgreSQL databases.

Documentation: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html

Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works and I can go to another issue!

Comment: @Luciferous, great to hear. Glad I could help

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking for button like "Answer is correct". This is my first experience of asking here.

Comment: sorry for molestation, but this option is disappeared again. I think it happened because I changed EF packages. Could it be the reason? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possibly, try to update to the latest packages if you can and make sure you have matching versions.